# Is it possible to target x64 .msi with WiX on a 32bit machine?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, 32bit-64bit

I'm developing SharePoint solutions on a virtual 32bit machine, and I use Wix to package the setup.

I'm targeting both 32bit and 64bit environments with my solutions, but in order to create 64bit MSI's, I need to have have a 64bit machine and the 64bit version of WiX.
Normally, this wouldn't be an issue, since I would have just simply use a 64bit dev environment.

But there are some issues with developing SharePoint solutions on a 64bit platform, which more or less forces me to develop on the 32bit platform.
Because of that, I can't create a 64bit MSI's, unless I copy the source files to a 64bit machine just to build the 64bit MSI, which feels a little bit cumbersome.

Is there any trick to flag/build the 64bit MSI package on my 32bit dev box, if it's even possible?

Comment: What about building the MSIs on a dedicated build server, and having a 32bit and a 64bit Build Agent?

Comment: The [`<Package />`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) element with the `Platform` attribute is all that's required. After all any MSI is a mere database. Of course testing is a different story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to run a 64-bit development machine to create a 64-bit MSI file.

What makes an MSI file "64-bit" is simply that the "Template Summary" field in the Summary Information Stream is set to "AMD64;1033" (one possible example) instead of "Intel;1033".

This MSDN article might provide you more [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd7a85k9(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Wix tools set is agnostic to platform, you need to install the [x64 version](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.0.5419.0/), and you need to use the proper flags inside the setup (there are various of places you need to be explicit about x64, more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372396(VS.85).aspx)).

Comment: Wait, why would you need to install the x64 version?